# Facebook comments on Drupal (same comments on all node)

Tags: php, facebook, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

On my Drupal website, I wanted to use Facebook comments. So I put the JavaScript SDK code on `html.tpl.php` and this:

```
   <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="5" data-width="540"></div>.
```

on my template file `node--article.tpl.php`.

So it is showing the Facebook comments on nodes. But the abnormal thing is : Same comments are being showed in all articles (nodes). A comment posted on article A will be shown on article B, article C and so on.

Why is this happening? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The `data-href` attribute tells the plugin what you want the comments to be made on – and here you are saying you want them to be made on your whole site. Change the value to the URL of the specific article in each case.

Comment: how can I write URL different for each article ? Or there is some value of URL that will make it unique for each article ?

Comment: An article (node) should already have a unique URL in drupal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get the URL of the comments page:

```
global $base_path;
$node_path = drupal_get_path_alias("node/" . $node->nid);
```

Then, change the `data-href` attribute to be:

```
data-href="http://example.com<?php print $base_path . $node_path; ?>"
```